# django templatetags into a views folder

Tags: python, django, django-templates, templatetags

I have a django project with the next folder structure:

```
+ project
+ - - app_1
+ - - - - __init__.py
+ - - - - models.py
+ - - - - forms.py
+ - - - - urls.py
+ - - - - templates
+ - - - - - - index.html
+ - - - - - - edit.html
+ - - - - - - show.html
+ - - - - views
+ - - - - - - __init__.py
+ - - - - - - index.py
+ - - - - - - edit.py
+ - - - - - - show.py
+ - - - - - - templatetags
+ - - - - - - - - __init__.py
+ - - - - - - - - custom_tags.py
```

When I try to call the custom_tags in the edit.html template for example

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

I get the next error:

> TemplateSyntaxError at /app_1/
>
> 'custom_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library custom_tags not found

My question is: Where i need put the templatetags folder or what i need to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your templatetags directory one level up, to right under your app_1 directory (as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Comment: I tried this before, but doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps also make sure you have "from django import template

register = template.Library()" in your custom_tags file

Answer (score 0):

The templatetags folder should be in the app folder:

```
+ project
+ - - app_1
+ - - - - __init__.py
+ - - - - templatetags
+ - - - - - - __init__.py
+ - - - - - - custom_tags.py
```

Depending on your server, you may need to restart it.

Comment: You are right, i needed restart the server and put the folder one level up like says @arilaan